# Nautilus launcher problem?

Tags: unity, nautilus, launcher

Here is my launcher when I open Nautilus with its corresponding icon (top one). It's supposed to stay on the top icon, not create a bottom icon.

[image: Nautilus on 2 icons.]
<sup>I had to hide personal information, sorry</sup>

I wonder what causes this behavior, because it really annoys me. I have tried replacing the original icon with the new one, but I've realized they're different, so I won't do it (there's a new "Open a New Window" option, that's the difference).

I have had this problem since I upgraded to 16.04 yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is made in Ubuntu 16.04 by design.

If you click a partition other that `/` in  Nautilus, it is opened in a new window with a new Launcher icon.

It is really annoying in some cases. A workaround is to create symlinks to partitions mount points in your Home directory and click them instead of directly clicking partitions.

You can also add these symlinks as your Favorites in Nautilus.

Another issue is when you upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04. It can be fixed by removing the icon from Launcher and adding it again.

Comment: As I stated in my answer (which you apparently voted to delete for some reason, VLQ maybe?), *the other icon should be removed*. Also, the workarounds are not enough for me, I'm the guy that changes his partitions every year or so.

Comment: 1. Your "answer" had one line when I voted to delete it and it did not answer the question.  2. It takes a second to create a symlink to a partition. 3. If you do not need a workaround, you can report it as a bug, but I doubt that it will be fixed. There is a chance though. 4. I upvoted the question ;-)

Comment: I just got home, and the answer has *three* lines now, and it's my own answer to the question. Sorry for VLQ :(

Comment: If your answer fixes your issue it can be undeleted.

Comment: It actually fixes the issue, read it yourself. It was intended to be as it reads, even though it's similar to your solution (*removing the icon from Launcher and adding it again*). But, you must ask terdon to undelete it and vote to undelete it if you want to.

Comment: I wrote to terdon to undelete. I can't vote, because he is a moderator.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't solve the original problem but can be a good workaround if you are tired of these spaghetti of nautilus windows when switching between partitions: *use* **nemo** *instead of* **nautilus**.

```
sudo apt install nemo
```

I'd rather use nautilus, but nemo is very similar and luckily is not integrated with unity launcher so it works as you would expect.

Comment: You can actually do both bold and italics, use `***text***`, like this: ***text***. Also, I think nemo is for cinnamon, if I'm not wrong, but also the "2nd choice". My problem is solved anyways. The problem wasn't the "spaghettis", it was the new window popping up everytime I clicked the icon. I might still install nemo, though.